# Keep specific columns within multindex

Tags: pandas

i have a daframe with à multiindex column with
1 short name and 1 long name

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('Code géographique', 'CODGEO'): {0: 1001},
                   ('Région', 'REG'): {0: 84},
                   ('Département', 'DEP'): {0: 1},
                   ('Libellé géographique', 'LIBGEO'): {0: "L'Abergement-Clémenciat"},
                   ('Population en 2020 (princ)', 'P20_POP'): {0: 806}})
```

i want to select columns based on short name
but i want to keep the multiindex structure. how can i do

```
columns_to_keep = ['CODGEO', 'REG', 'DEP']
```

Comment: You have several options, for example: `df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, columns_to_keep]]`